# How do I know the processor family in linux?

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit

```
Processor family
  1. Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8 (MK8)
  2. Intel P4 / older Netburst based Xeon (MPSC)
  3. Core 2/newer Xeon (MCORE2) (NEW)
  4. Intel Atom (MATOM) (NEW)
> 5. Generic-x86-64 (GENERIC_CPU)
```

I'm compiling the linux kernel,how can I know which one to choose?

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 2926.030
cache size  : 3072 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx lm constant_tsc up pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5852.06
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: You have a Core(TM)2 Duo - which appears to match option 3.

Comment: I think an answer here should be made less specific on the model the author has, and assist all users of the Linux Kernel in figuring out the right answer here for their particular model of CPU. For example, I have AMD Ryzen CPUs - how would I find the right answer to this prompt while configuring a kernel build? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

and you will see the processor what you have.

In your case is option 3.

From kernel help about MCORE2

> Select this for Intel Core 2 and newer
>   Core 2 Xeons (Xeon 51xx and 53xx)
>   CPUs. You can distinguish newer from
>   older Xeons by the CPU family in
>   /proc/cpuinfo. Newer ones have 6 and
>   older ones 15 (not a typo)

Comment: I've pasted the cpu info here,but which family does it belong?